# How do I sort a text file by the highest number using Java

Tags: java, sorting

I currently have a small problem, I'm making a game in Java and I'm making a highscore for it. I made it save the name of the player and the score into a text file. When I try to print it out it obviously shows in the order of the text file, how would I sort it so it used the highest score first.

Example from the text file:

```
John: 12
Bert: 16
Oscar: 18
Eric: 25
Carl: 9
```

How I want it:

```
Eric: 25
Oscar: 18
Bert: 16
John: 12
Carl: 9
```

Comment: YOu can use [Arrays#sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7//docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))

Comment: Whats the code you use to print on the file? It would be better to print it ordered instead of printing and reordering. (Unless you cant change the print code...)

Comment: Show us your code so we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

try using sort  `Collections.sort(list);`

Answer (score 1):

Use a sorted collection like `TreeMap` which keeps its entries (key-value mappings) in natural order of their keys. Since, you want to sort on the high scores keep your scores as the keys and player names as their values.

```
// instantiate your sorted collection
Map<Integer, String> highestScores = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

// setup a file reader
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file")));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // read your file line by line
    String[] playerScores = line.split(": ");
    // populate your collection with score-player mappings
    highestScores.put(Integer.valueOf(playerScores[1]), playerScores[0]);
}

// iterate in descending order
for (Integer score : highestScores.descendingKeySet()) {
    System.out.println(highestScores.get(score) + ": " + score);
}
```

***Output***

```
Eric: 25
Oscar: 18
Bert: 16
John: 12
Carl: 9
```

***EDIT:***
It's very likely that two or more players could have the same high scores. So, the sorted collection would have to be a little bit more complex but if you've understood the one above you would have no troubles understanding this one.

Instead of mapping a score to a player we would have to map it to a `List` of players (with the same high score) now:

```
// {key - value} = {high score - {list, of, players}}
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> highestScores =
                               new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file")));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] playerScores = line.split(": ");
    Integer score = Integer.valueOf(playerScores[1]);
    List<String> playerList = null;

    // check if a player with this score already exists
    if ((playerList = highestScores.get(score)) == null) { // if NOT,
        playerList = new ArrayList<String>(1); // CREATE a new list
        playerList.add(playerScores[0]);
        highestScores.put(Integer.valueOf(playerScores[1]), playerList);
    } else { // if YES, ADD to the existing list
        playerList.add(playerScores[0]);
    }
}

// iterate in descending order
for (Integer score : highestScores.descendingKeySet()) {
    for (String player : highestScores.get(score)) { // iterate over player list
        System.out.println(player + ": " + score);
    }
}
```

***Output***

```
Eric: 25
Oscar: 18
Bert: 16
John: 12 *
Jane: 12 *
Carl: 9
```